# Zoom windows launch with a completely blank window

Tags: fedora, wayland, zoom

Whenever I attempt to launch Zoom from Terminal, nothing happens.  When I try `zoom --no-sandbox`, it launches a blank window that only has an outline.  I can't interact with any 'invisible' buttons either. Currently have the RPM version installed, but this issue also occurs with the Flatpak version.  Does anyone know a possible alternative workaround other than switching to X11 display?  Here are my specs below:

OS: Fedora 35

DE: Gnome 41.4

CPU: Intel i7-10870H (16) @ 5GHz

GPU: GeForce RTX 2060 (ver. 510)

Display: XWayland

Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix the problem on Wayland by going to the zoomus.conf file at ~/.config/zoomus.conf (or ./var/us.zoom.Zoom/config if using Flatpak) and setting enableAlphaBuffer=false to solve the transparent window issue!

Comment: thanks a lot - that worked perfectly for me

Comment: works for Ubuntu 22.04 as well